# scenario in Allure Report

Tags: bdd, allure

I have the following scenario outline.I want to change my scenario outline description for every username and password pair.

```
Scenario Outline:Login functionality for a social networking site.
Given user navigates to Facebook
When I enter Username as "<username>" and Password as "<password>"
Then login should be unsuccessful

Examples:
| username  | password  | 
| username1 | password1 | 
| username2 | password2 |
```

I searched in other sites and I got a solution that we can pass param in 
outline as like in Given,When and Then.

```
Scenario Outline:Login functionality for a social networking site <site-name>.
```

But do we have any other latest solution without passing parameter in scenario outline?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of Cucumber and programming language you are using, there a few ways to achieve what you want to:

if you are using Java and Cucumber JVM 1.x, then you can upgrade to Cucumber JVM 2.x - it supports adding Examples parameters to report out of the box. It looks like that:

[Cucumber JVM 2.x Allure Report example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muIox.png)

Another way, again example for Java, would be to use Allure Lifecycle to modify Scenario name in report, like that:

```
@Given("^countryIso3 is ([A-Z]{3})$")
public void countryIso3(String countryIso3) throws Throwable {
    this.countryIso3 = countryIso3;
    Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase(testResult -> {
        String name = testResult.getName();
        testResult.setName(name + " ["+countryIso3+"]");
    });
}
```

[Using Allure Lifecycle Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak9jh.png)